# AngularJS routing and CodeIgniter as API

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter

I am making a one page application using AngularJS routing and CodeIgniter as an API. I want to know the file structure and any changes to .htaccess of the API that do not allow the users to access the API in any case.

Comment: When you are using angularJS as frontend framework you need to compromise with security.

Comment: Why would you say that?